# How check and filter emails in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an android application that sends and receives filtered emails from a particular email account. I made the send of the mail, but my question is that if there is a way to receive, I mean to check a email and filter the new email only from a particular account, everything in the android app.